# Resource ícones JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Boa tarde.

Estou tendo problemas com meu aplicativo.
Ele executa com alteração do ícone no `JFrame`.
Ao compilar ele para: "Runnable Jar file" e compilar com: Launch4j para binary, o aplicativo simplesmente não abre.

Estou alterando o ícone por esse comando:

```java
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/z/app.png")));
```

Comment: Alguém me dá um help por favor!

Comment: Não há informações suficientes na sua pergunta para que alguém possa elaborar alguma resposta útil. Em que contexto você altera o ícone? Como é que o `/z/app.png` está empacotado na aplicação? Consegue fazer um código [mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: /z/app.png está dentro da pasta do projeto no eclipse. expecificamente: F:\Utilitários\Desenvolvimento\- Eclipse\QuickStage\bin\z dentro da pasta z está: "app.png" e "tray.png"

Comment: Você consegue ver se o ícone aperece em algum lugar dentro do arquivo JAR? E se este lugar é o lugar esperado? Em especial o uso do `getClass().getResource(String)` é algo muito sensível a falhar dependendo se a aplicação está ou não encapsulada em um arquivo JAR. Novamente, um MCVE ajudaria bastante para você obter respostas melhores e mais rápido: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Victor campeão! Como posso visualizar dentro ".jar"? Sim, estou tentando utilizar MVC. Mais nessa parte de image não sei como ficaria dentro dele.

Comment: Renomeia ele para ".zip" e abre como se fosse um ".zip". E não confunda MVC com MCVE, são coisas completamente diferentes!

Answer (score 1):

Criei 1 package com nome de img e alterei o diretório para:

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/img/app.png")));
```

Comment: Fazer isso deu certo ou o problema ainda persiste?

Comment: Resolveu Victor. Após ter criada 1 package e colocado o nome img e arrastado de uma pasta as images.png para a pasta img no eclipse e referênciando novamente resolveu o problema. Até o "tray system" que é ocultar ao lado do relógio do windows parou de dá erro. Obrigado pela atenção! e pela sua ajuda